# unable to cast SKLabelNode to get text property back

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I may be making this more complicated then necessary.

What I'm trying to do is cast a Node to SKLabelNode when I know that it's going to be an SKLabelNode so I can call the .text property on it in the touchesBegan method.

What's happening now is the inner if condition seems to be failing as it's not getting in that if block (it is getting into the outer if block). I did a printobject on touchedNode and it says it's of type SKLabelNode too so I'm not sure what the deal is.

```
let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationinNode(self))

if touchedNode.name == "english1"{
 if let answerNode = touchedNode as? SKLabelNode{
  println("hi")
 }
}
```

So basically, does anyone have an idea how what's wrong with my code OR how to get the text property from a touchedNode when it's a SKLabelNode?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `touchedNode.isMemberOfClass(SKLabelNode)` Also is userinteractionenabled set to true?

Comment: @Kendel thank you for your comment! I have now set userinteractionenabled to true. And everything seems to be working with my code now. Much appreciated. If you make your comment an answer I'll mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initiliaze the node be sure to do `node.userInteractionEnabled = true`